# echoing array index and getting a blank page

Tags: php

```
<?

$array = array('eggs', 'bacon', 'football', 'baseball', 'ford', 'toyota'); 

$rand_index = mt_rand(0, count($array) / 2 - 1) * 2; 
?>



<?php echo "$array[$rand_index]"; ?><?php echo "$array[$rand_index+1]"; ?>
```

i dunno why this script doesn't work. I want to echo both values but can't

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just do...

```
<?

$array = array('eggs', 'bacon', 'football', 'baseball', 'ford', 'toyota'); 

$rand_index = array_rand($array); 
?>
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

By the way, if you want to do this...

```
<?php echo "$array[$rand_index]"; ?><?php echo "$array[$rand_index+1]"; ?>
```

Just introduce the braces around it like so...

```
<?php echo "{$array[$rand_index]}"; ?>
```

(it [does work](http://codepad.org/5RtdfeqY) when using a PHP variable as an array subscript).

But in that example, **it would be better to avoid wrapping with string delimiters**. It is confusing and only adds extra overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the quotes.  PHP won't parse the code inside of strings, thankfully :)

```
echo $array[$rand_index];
```

**Edit:** Just wrong, apparently. I didn't realize you could interpolate arithmetic even inside curly brackets. Learn something new every day. Thanks, alex.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain again :P but in the example linked it *does* do arithmetic - it adds 1 to `$i` to subscript the array.

Comment: @alex Yeah, I saw that.  I intended to agree with you in my Edit, but perhaps it didn't come across.

Answer (score 0):

`$rand_index+1` is creating a syntax error.

try doing:

```
<?php 
$rand_index2 = $rand_index + 1;
echo "$array[$rand_index]"; 
echo "$array[$rand_index2]";
?>
```

Comment: Oh yea... both of those other answers are actually more logical. Use those :-P